# Can you suggest me some open source projects in Javascript or PHP that I can study easily?

Tags: php, javascript, open-source

I have come to learn that my learning habits in programming is by looking at other people codes and hack it myself. My favourite languages are PHP and Javascript, so I want you to please share to me some open source projects that I can look at. jQuery and Wordpress are way too big and advance for me, please share me open source projects that are not hard to hack. Thank you.

Comment: wow. jQuery != wordpress.  wordpress is a template thing. jQuery is just a javascript library.

Comment: @Neal OP just meant that jQuery and Wordpress (examples of JavaScript and PHP libraries) were too complicated, not that they were the same

Comment: Raymond: this question is going to be closed due to its subjective nature, especially because you are asking for a list of things. Perhaps if you reconstructed the question so that people could give a definitive answer, for some particular topic you are interested in for example, it would stay open.

Comment: I see, I was warned that this was going to be closed but I still posted this question. I Didn't thought that SO is strict at this kind of question. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: If you want to find open source code to hack on, just go to [GitHub](http://github.com) and look for projects and gists in the languages you are interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [`docco`](http://jashkenas.github.com/docco/) annotated source code like

- [`underscore`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html)
- [`backbone`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html)